# File access is denied

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

I'm using SQL command within FoxPro 6.0 command window, and encountered the "File access is denied."

My SQL command is:

```
SELECT * FROM main.dbf WHERE Client = "ABC"
```

Situation:

- Windows 7 Pro
- FoxPro 6.0 main.dbf is shared to many users.
- main.dbf is not *hidden* and is not *write only*

Any comments will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this DBF file on a shared drive? If so, another user may have the file open Exclusive, or you are trying to open the file Exclusive. By default, Foxpro tries to open tables exclusively.

In the command window or your program, issue these commands:

```
SET EXCLUSIVE OFF
USE main SHARED
SELECT * FROM main WHERE Client = "ABC"
```

If you still get the error, then you may want to download a tool that will show you a list of users that have the file open. Perhaps one of them have the DBF opened exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to open the DBF file in exclusive mode:

```
SET EXCLUSIVE ON
```

Then perform your SQL query.

Comment: Then, it looks like the file is being used by another app or a network user.

Comment: Yes, the file is saved on a shared drive. Sorry for not stating this clearly in my question. Thank you so much!